# SELECT , GROUP AND DISPLAY IN TABULAR FORM

Tags: mysql

[image: DATA TABLE]

I Have a table as above. How can I get an output (as shown below) with a single mysql query.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT location,
       AVG(CASE WHEN qtr = 'Q1' THEN achievement END) q1-average,
       AVG(CASE WHEN qtr = 'Q2' THEN achievement END) q2-average
FROM sourcetable
-- WHERE year = '2018'
GROUP BY location;
```

Comment: Thanks so very much :-). It really works and solved my problem.

Comment: Another issue. From the output generated with the query above, now I want to count for Location-1 and Q1-AVERAGE / Q2-AVERAGE, how many falls in the range between 3.0-4.0, 4.0-5.0, 5.0-6.0, 6.0-7.0 etc. Similarly for Location-2 and Location-3. Can it be done in a single query on top of the above query?

Comment: @RajorsheMistry *how many falls in the range between 3.0-4.0* What's a problem? `COUNT(CASE WHEN location = 'location 1' AND achievement BETWEEN 3.0 AND 4.0 THEN 1 END)`. Remember - if condition not matched (none condition matched if there is more than one WHEN), CASE returns NULL, which is ignored by COUNT/SUM/AVG.

Comment: Yes. That's the query I was looking for. But I want to use it in the same query. Can it be used like this - COUNT (CASE WHEN LOCATION='Location-1' and achievement BETWEEN 3.0 AND 4.0 THEN1 END (SELECT location,
       AVG(CASE WHEN qtr = 'Q1' THEN achievement END) q1-average,
       AVG(CASE WHEN qtr = 'Q2' THEN achievement END) q2-average
FROM sourcetable
GROUP BY location)

Comment: @RajorsheMistry *Can it be used* Of course... the grouping frame is the same, so simply add calculated fields to SELECT clause.

Comment: Tried of course, but reason for asking because all endeavors are futile. Anyways, thanks for your support :-)

Comment: @RajorsheMistry And - because `location` is a GROUP BY expresssion, you do not need it in WHEN condition. The condition by `qtr` and `achievement` is enough. And none sub-SELECT is needed.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT location,
       AVG(SELECT achievment FROM location WHERE QTR='Q1'),
       AVG(SELECT achievment FROM location WHERE QTR='Q2') 
FROM location 
GROUP BY location
```

Comment: Wrong query. Test it on shown data...

Comment: This query is not working on the test as well as on actual data.